# Associate a VIP to an endpoint on an Azure VM

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I am attempting to add a VIP to a VM. I am following the Microsoft document on how to do this however I am getting an error when completing the final command.

First I created my VIP and assigned it to the VM as stated in the document. It then says I have to associate it with an endpoint by using this command 
[image]

so I entered in powershell the following:

[image]

And Lastly.. I get these messages after hitting enter:

[image]

It appears that it's not working as intended, and it's not showing in the list of endpoints for the VM either. I am kind of lost as to what the problem is or what I can do about the error. I think it could be something with the way I am entering the command, but I am unsure. Hoping someone here can help me out.

Comment: First: the backticks (`) are used for linebreaks. Remove them when you write everything on one line. Second: the "internal server error" might be just that or something with the state of the VM is not as expected?

Comment: First check whether vip has been added or not using this command-
Get-AzureVM -Name "thevmname" -ServiceName "theservicename" | Get-AzureEndpoint | select { $_.Vip }

Comment: Swonkie is right, remove the backtick, than it should do..

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the reply. I tried to remove the ticks, but same error. for some reason it doesn't like the Update-AzureVM